# variable $base_path is not working

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to get the value of base_path variable in PHP (on lamp server) .

I have kept the code insider beta_test directory inside www directly.

i.e, base path function should return "  /beta_test/ " . But it is returning just single slash ( "/" ) .

The code that I tried is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print base_path(); ?>sites/all/themes/people10/slider/call.js"></script>
```

Expected output is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/beta_test/sites/all/themes/people10/slider/call.js"></script>
```

But its giving

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/people10/slider/call.js"></script>
```

I am using php version 5.3.3.Can anyone please help me in getting  this issue solved? I am newbie to php and drupal .

Comment: The `Expected output is` ??? You are tried running `sites/all/themes/people10/slider/call.js` .. am a bit lost

Comment: You might need to escape your code by prepending four spaces to each line so it displays correctly.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. If still it is not working then use `echo` and give a try.

Comment: I think you call the base_path function from outside of drupal, when yo say in PHP on a LAMP server

Answer (score 1):

`print $base_path` returns the folder name where Drupal is installed.

The complete base URL is `print $base_url`.